# Is Task.Delay non blocking?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

`Task.Delay` uses `System.Threading.Timer` internally. Main question is `System.Threading.Timer` non-blocking for my application? If I make:

```
await Task.Delay(15)
```

Does code bellow utilize threads for 15ms? Or will it use OS to make callback. Where to find information about this?

Comment: .NET threads are (conceptually) different from OS threads. You're already quite a few levels of abstraction away from the OS. What's your actual concern?

Comment: I simply want everything non-blocking. I am pretty sure that it non-blocking, otherwise it will not be a method of the Task. Just need a proof. Unfortunately, I cannot find one.

Comment: So long as the runtime is managing things efficiently, what does it matter whether a) No "threads" are used for this delay, b) A single thread deals with all delays within the process, or c) A thread is consumed for each delay requested? (There may be other options also)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Jeffrey Richter (page 748):

> Internally, the thread pool has just one thread that it uses for all Timer objects. This thread knows when the next Timer object’s time is due. When the next Timer object is due, the thread wakes up, and internally calls ThreadPool’s QueueUserWorkItem to enter an entry into the thread pool’s queue, causing your callback method to get called.

That means that you'll have at least two worker threads when timer is executed: one - internal for timer and another - for the actual worker process.